# Can I display a set of eigenvectors across two pages?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

I was wondering if its possible to split an array over two pages since I have a huge formula for my array? I already rotated the formula and reduced the size, but I still have to split it over two pages I think for it to be readable.I used the following packages and code are (sorry beforehand I don't know how to display my code other than writing the latex equations):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,openany]{report}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalefnt}

Eigenvector (D12): \scalefont{0.3}{\begin{equation} \rotatebox{-90}{$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \frac{6\,\left(d-2\right)\,\left(\frac{d}{3}-\frac{2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}{6}+\frac{2^{2/3}\,\left(d^2-1\right)}{3\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{3}\right)}{d\,\left(d+2\right)}-\frac{{\left(2\,d-2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}+\frac{2\,2^{2/3}\,\left(d^2-1\right)}{{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-2\right)}^2}{3\,d\,\left(d+2\right)}-\frac{4\,\left(d-1\right)}{d+2} & -\frac{4\,\left(d-1\right)}{d+2}-\frac{{\left(4\,d+2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}-\frac{2\,2^{2/3}\,\left(d^2-1\right)}{{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}+\frac{2\,2^{2/3}\,\sqrt{3}\,\left(\frac{2^{2/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{2/3}\,1{}\mathrm{i}}{4}+d^2\,1{}\mathrm{i}-\mathrm{i}\right)}{{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-4\right)}^2}{12\,d\,\left(d+2\right)}+\frac{6\,\left(d-2\right)\,\left(\frac{d}{3}+\frac{2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}{12}-\frac{2^{2/3}\,\left(d^2-1\right)}{6\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}+\frac{2^{2/3}\,\sqrt{3}\,\left(\frac{2^{2/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{2/3}\,1{}\mathrm{i}}{4}+d^2\,1{}\mathrm{i}-\mathrm{i}\right)}{6\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{3}\right)}{d\,\left(d+2\right)} & -\frac{4\,\left(d-1\right)}{d+2}-\frac{{\left(\frac{2\,2^{2/3}\,\left(d^2-1\right)}{{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}-4\,d+\frac{2\,2^{2/3}\,\sqrt{3}\,\left(\frac{2^{2/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{2/3}\,1{}\mathrm{i}}{4}+d^2\,1{}\mathrm{i}-\mathrm{i}\right)}{{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}+4\right)}^2}{12\,d\,\left(d+2\right)}-\frac{6\,\left(d-2\right)\,\left(\frac{2^{2/3}\,\left(d^2-1\right)}{6\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-\frac{2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}{12}-\frac{d}{3}+\frac{2^{2/3}\,\sqrt{3}\,\left(\frac{2^{2/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{2/3}\,1{}\mathrm{i}}{4}+d^2\,1{}\mathrm{i}-\mathrm{i}\right)}{6\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{d\,\left(d+2\right)}\\ \frac{6\,\left(\frac{d}{3}-\frac{2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}{6}+\frac{2^{2/3}\,\left(d^2-1\right)}{3\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{3}\right)}{d}-\frac{{\left(2\,d-2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}+\frac{2\,2^{2/3}\,\left(d^2-1\right)}{{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-2\right)}^2}{6\,d\,\left(d-1\right)}-3 & -\frac{{\left(4\,d+2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}-\frac{2\,2^{2/3}\,\left(d^2-1\right)}{{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}+\frac{2\,2^{2/3}\,\sqrt{3}\,\left(\frac{2^{2/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{2/3}\,1{}\mathrm{i}}{4}+d^2\,1{}\mathrm{i}-\mathrm{i}\right)}{{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-4\right)}^2}{24\,d\,\left(d-1\right)}+\frac{2^{2/3}\,\left(\frac{2^{2/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{2/3}}{4}-2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}-d^2+2^{1/3}\,d\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}+1-\sqrt{3}\,1{}\mathrm{i}+\sqrt{3}\,d^2\,1{}\mathrm{i}+\frac{2^{2/3}\,\sqrt{3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{2/3}\,1{}\mathrm{i}}{4}\right)}{d\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-3 & -\frac{{\left(\frac{2\,2^{2/3}\,\left(d^2-1\right)}{{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}-4\,d+\frac{2\,2^{2/3}\,\sqrt{3}\,\left(\frac{2^{2/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{2/3}\,1{}\mathrm{i}}{4}+d^2\,1{}\mathrm{i}-\mathrm{i}\right)}{{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}+4\right)}^2}{24\,d\,\left(d-1\right)}+\frac{2^{2/3}\,\left(\frac{2^{2/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{2/3}}{4}-2^{1/3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}-d^2+2^{1/3}\,d\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}+1+\sqrt{3}\,1{}\mathrm{i}-\sqrt{3}\,d^2\,1{}\mathrm{i}-\frac{2^{2/3}\,\sqrt{3}\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{2/3}\,1{}\mathrm{i}}{4}\right)}{d\,{\left(\sqrt{d^2\,{\left(d-1\right)}^2\,\left(17\,d^2+40\,d+24\right)}-d^3-3\,d^2+4\right)}^{1/3}}-3\\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right) $}  \end{equation}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch How do I do that exactly? I can attach a pdf of the output if that makes it any easier, but not sure how to get tex to display the code.

Comment: We don't want the output. We want a compiliable-as-is minimal source document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. See [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: @frabjous I  have added the output of my code as well as a minimal source document. I hope things are more clear now.

Comment: @Mensch I hope things are more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like your readers to have even a fighting chance to understand what's going on, you need to re-express the elements of the eigenvectors in terms of their common factors, possibly along the following lines (no guarantee that I got it right!):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,openany]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\providecommand\dsq{d^{\mkern1mu 2}}

\begin{document}
The eigenvector matrix $D$ is given by
\[
D=\begin{pmatrix}
  d_{11} & d_{12} & d_{13} \\
  d_{21} & d_{22} & d_{23} \\
  1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\] 
where \allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*} 
d_{11}
&= \frac{6(d-2)V}{d(d+2)}
  -\frac{{6V}^2}{3d(d+2)}
  -\frac{4(d-1)}{d+2} \\
d_{12}
&=-\frac{(W+X)^2}{12d(d+2)} 
  +\frac{6(d-2)(Y+Z)}{d(d+2)}
  -\frac{4(d-1)}{d+2} \\
d_{13} 
&=-\frac{(W-X)^2}{12d(d+2)}
  -\frac{6(d-2)(Y-Z)}{d(d+2)}
  -\frac{4(d-1)}{d+2} \\
d_{21}
&=\frac{6V}{d}
 -\frac{(6V)^2}{6d(d-1)}
 -3 \\
d_{22}
&=-\frac{(W+X)^2}{24d(d-1)} 
  +\frac{2^{2/3}(K-L)}{d\,U}
  -3
\\
d_{23}
&= -\frac{(W-X)^2}{24d(d-1)} 
   +\frac{2^{2/3}\left(K+L\right)}{d\,U}
   -3 
\\
\shortintertext{and}
U&= (\sqrt{\dsq (d-1)^2(17\dsq +40d+24)}-d^3-3\dsq +4)^{1/3}\\
V&= \frac{d}{3}-\frac{2^{1/3}U}{6}+\frac{2^{2/3}(\dsq -1)}{3U}-\frac{1}{3}\\
W&= 2\cdot2^{2/3}\sqrt{3}(2^{2/3}U^2 \mathrm{i}/4+(\dsq -1) \mathrm{i})/U \\
X&= 4d+2^{1/3}U-2\cdot2^{2/3}(\dsq -1)/U-4 \\
Y&= 2^{2/3}\sqrt{3}(2^{2/3}U^2 \mathrm{i}/4+(\dsq -1) \mathrm{i})/(6U) \\
Z&= \frac{d}{3}+\frac{2^{1/3}U}{12}-\frac{2^{2/3}(\dsq -1)}{6U}-\frac{1}{3}  \\
K&= 2^{2/3}U^2/4-2^{1/3}U-\dsq +2^{1/3}d\,U+1 \\
L&= \sqrt{3} \mathrm{i}-\sqrt{3}\dsq  \mathrm{i}-2^{2/3}\sqrt{3}U^2 \mathrm{i}/4 \,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats certainly a solution thanks. However, as I have quite many of these eigenvectors and I'm only including these in the appendix of my document for reference does there exist a way to split the rotated array over two pages?

Comment: @PianoMath - I take it that some program (Matlab?) produced LaTeX code to typeset the eigenvectors at a microscopic font size. In my opinion, you should either take the time to give your readers a fighting chance to decipher them, say along the lines pursued in my answer, or otherwise just not bother typesetting the material. Nobody is going to spend more than a fraction of a second looking at some illegible mess. (And, yes, spreading the vectors across two pages will still assure some illegible mess.) Could you maybe provide the (Matlab?) code that calcualtes the eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes, you are correct the code is generated using MatLab. I have made a question  on mathworks where you can see my code. (The link is given by  https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1718850-interpreting-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-when-using-symbolic-toolbox?s_tid=srchtitle  or you can search "Interpreting eigenvalues and eigenvectors when using symbolic toolbox" in Matlab answers). 

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Among others a huge eigenvector is given by the matrix:

Comment: \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right). I got a pretty decent representation of the eigenvalues, but the eigenvectors scare me as they are so large! How would I even create vertical vectors where expressions are split along multiple vertical lines? Any help would be massively appreciated )